# Erlang, connecting nodes across the internet in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, erlang, software-distribution

I've started playing alittle with erlang, and find it most interesting.

My problem is this, I would like to set up a server to run a webservice. The service should be writen in erlang, and should be easily mutated, that Is I would like to be able to do hot codeswap alot, the code is writen and tested on another machine, it there a way to deploy code easily from one erlang noce to another, without having to wrap it up in files and transfer the files?

I think I remmember hearing something about being able to pass closures around inside the erlang VM, is this doable? or perhaps even updating threads on the server machine with the compiled code on the development machine?

I know this sounds like a risky way of doing things, and it is, but its what my mind has settled on.

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7917108/431620 and carefully read its answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7927649/431620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you want to load a module from one node to another. In this case you can use the bif `nl(Module)` which loads the module "Module" on all nodes. Or you can either use `nc(Module)` Of course the nodes must share the same cookie and must be connected (see `net_adm:ping(Node)`)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really get away from transferring files to your target deployment machine. At the very least your going to need to send down the new versions of the modules.

Once you have updated the modules your options for updating code of the fly range from simply reloading a module (something like [code:load_file/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#load_file-1)). A full blown [OTP upgrade](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html) ([rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar) may help here) or something in-between (like [updo](https://github.com/permelin/updo) or the mochiweb [reloader](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/reloader.erl) module). It really depends on what you are trying to do, the dependencies between the changed modules, etc.