# Code.compile_string and Code.eval in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I want to create a module at run time in Elixir using a string which contains the module code. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223238/how-do-you-create-and-load-modules-dynamically-at-runtime-in-elixir-or-erlang) question it has been said about Code.compile_string and Code.eval methods. Aren't they supporting to Elixir? I'm getting compile errors while using them.

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Code.eval/2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `Code.eval_string`. You can see the docs here: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3