# .. automatically completes module path after import. MyMo.. works the same as MyModule. by autocomplete, ends with MyMo..:ok

Tags: import, pattern-matching, elixir

Adding an extra dot allows modules to "autocomplete".

"My" code:

```
defmodule Rec do
  def msgurr(text, n) when n <= 1 do
    IO.puts text
  end

  def msgurr(text, n) do
    IO.puts text
    msgurr(text, n - 1)
  end
end
```

When I reference it, as follows:

```
iex(6)> R..print_multiple_times("blah", 5)
blah
blah
blah
blah
blah
R..:ok
iex(7)> E..print_multiple_times("hello", 3)
hello
hello
hello
E..:ok
```

However, the following import command, with a call similar to the online documentation, does not work:

```
iex(8)> ..msgurr("Hello!", 3) 
** (SyntaxError) iex:8: syntax error before: '..'
```

Why is this?

How does this sort of auto-completing import statement work in Elixir?

Is there any easy documentation for this?

I read through this question:

[How do you create and load modules dynamically at runtime in Elixir, or Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223238/how-do-you-create-and-load-modules-dynamically-at-runtime-in-elixir-or-erlang)

However, it doesn't seem to say much about this little ".." thing for importing.

I haven't tested it out in an actual script, just the `iex` interpreter.

Comment: Maybe you can use tab completion? It is also just one keystroke if the completion is unambiguous, but you know exactly what you get and the result is "normal" Elixir code.

Comment: I don't mean tab completion, I mean that the actual resolution of the module happens with completion.  Maybe "completion" isn't the right word.  Regardless, I do need to install the Elixir mode.

Comment: Yes, but I mean why do you want to do this? If you just want to save keystrokes, tab completion should get you there. IMHO, the "ellipsis" is a code smell and should only be used in iex for debugging, not in actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The extra dot is actually creating a range, so IEx will be smart enough to autocomplete to any imported function.

This is calling function `foo` in `R`:

```
R.foo
```

This is creating a range with `R` on the left side and whatever is `foo` on the right side:

```
R..foo
```

You don't need `..` to autocomplete. Just hit tab on whatever expression:

```
is_at<TAB>
```

should autocomplete to `is_atom`.

Comment: Would this also work if one replaced "R" with "RecursionTestA" in the first call mentioned?